# Is there any function as TentativeRoughFix in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-selection

I have applied Boruta on my dataset to determine the importance of features with respect to a predictor variable. However it is unable to determine the importance of several features.They are being shown as tentative.
Is there any function as TentativeRoughFix in Python. The TentativeRoughFix function is present in R-language. If there is any such function, can anybody guide me towards it. Or any suggestion regarding how to change the importance of variables from "tentative" to "important" or "not important" in python will be very appreciated.

Comment: What statistical package are you using?

Comment: I am using Boruta. https://github.com/danielhomola/boruta_py

Comment: So you have too many things in feat_selector.support_weak_? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I do not know how to handle this issue. I have not tried anything so far

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options for feature selection in scikit-learn (see [docu](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html)).

There is also a Boruta python implementation [Boruta_py](https://github.com/danielhomola/boruta_py), but I never tested it.